# Javascript: How to add data to Blob object sequentially after URL generation

Tags: javascript, blob

I'm creating a Blob object from a list of scripts like and then creating object URL from Blob to inject script tag into html page.

```js
var myScriptList = [
  'var a = 1;',
  'var b = 2;',
  'var c = a+b;'
];

var myBlobObject = new Blob(myScriptList, {type: 'text/javascript'});
var urlToBlob = URL.createObjectURL(myBlobObject);

alert(urlToBlob);
```

The problem happens when I need to append new items to my previous blob with same URL. I did this by creating new Blob object concating previous list with new items:

```js
var myScriptList = [
  'var a = 1;',
  'var b = 2;',
  'var c = a+b;'
];

var myBlobObject = new Blob(myScriptList, {type: 'text/javascript'});
var urlToBlob = URL.createObjectURL(myBlobObject);

alert(urlToBlob);

myScriptList.push('console.log(c)');

myBlobObject = new Blob(myScriptList, {type: 'text/javascript'});

// Problem is following line returns new URL
urlToBlob = URL.createObjectURL(myBlobObject);

alert(urlToBlob);
```

But I need to keep previous URL for my new Object. Is it possible? How can I do this?

Comment: You can't do that. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I am creating a js file from some scripts, and inject them into page. Users may debug these files (which I dynamically added to page), so if the URL changes, any breakpoint created by user will be lost @TamasHegedus

Comment: The best you can do is adding new script tags with the new parts of the code.

Comment: Or use a backend, serve the dynamic js file on a url, and force the page to reload when your script changes.

Comment: No, reloading the page is not a good solution @TamasHegedus

Comment: that's how Youtube works, how they are keep fetching the data and their blob remain same every time. Please help me I want the same funtionality

Answer (score -1):

From:
https://violentmonkey.github.io/posts/inject-scripts-with-blob-urls/

Here is an example how to use normal and blob way, and please see the output:

```js
{
  const s = document.createElement('script');
  s.textContent = 'console.log(1)';
  document.body.appendChild(s);
  document.body.removeChild(s);
}

{
  const s = document.createElement('script');
  const b = new Blob(['console.log(2)'], { type: 'text/javascript' });
  const u = URL.createObjectURL(b);
  s.src = u;
  document.body.appendChild(s);
  document.body.removeChild(s);
  URL.revokeObjectURL(u);
}

console.log(3);
```

Output:

```
1
3
2
```

It is not in the same order since the `src` is async.